# LogStash: Convert to integer in mutate has no effect

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I cannot get integer comparisons to work in logstash filter, using logstash 6.4.2. When I try I still get a string, and comparisons '> 10' fail with runtime exception when reading logs: 'comparison of String with 10 failed'

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

```
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "[@metadata][day]" => "%{+dd}"} # generates '06' on 6. of month
        convert => { "[@metadata][day]" => "integer" }
        add_field => { "testDay" => "%{[@metadata][day]}" } # Copy     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from Badger (elastic.co forum):

This is your issue. None of the converts are happening. A mutate filter does things in a fixed order, and once it has done all of that it decorates the event (that's the call to filter_matched()), which implements common options like add_field. That means the the convert executes before the add_field, so none of the fields exist when you try to convert them. Split your mutate into two

-- 
Thx to Badger for quickly resolving my question at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/howto-integer-comparison-in-logstash-filter/175675, with answer posted here for future reference.

Comment: Here's the official documentation on this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-proc_order